# Using Haskell REPL in IntelliJ

Tags: haskell, intellij-idea

I installed the Haskell Plugin in IntelliJ. Opening the Haskell REPL produces the following Errors

Opening the first time:

```
10:10:05 NoClassDefFoundError:      com/intellij/execution/console/LanguageConsoleViewImpl
```

If it try to open it again

```
10:20:40 NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/execution/process/ConsoleHistoryModel
```

Here are table summarizing the versions of my tools.

```
+================+==========+
|      Tool      | Version  |
+================+==========+
| GHC            |    7.8.3 |
+----------------+----------+
| Cabal          | 1.18.0.5 |
+----------------+----------+
| Intellij       |   14.1.1 |
+----------------+----------+
| Haskell Plugin |    0.5.0 |
+----------------+----------+
```

The REPL Console works in Eclipse with the EclipseFP Plugin. Compiling and starting a Haskell program (in Intellij) works fine.

Does anyone know how to fix this, so I use Haskell REPL in Intellij?